# Hashalgorithm and hashencoding

Tags: java, encryption, jboss

I am using build in Jboss `login-module`. It has to encode what user entered as a password and compare with encrypted password in `db`.

```
<module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
<module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
```

For storing password in db I use following line

```
newUser.setPassword(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(purePassword.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

When I debug my application it appears:

- encrypted password from DB = `MTIzNDU2Nzg=`
- encrypted password from
  user login = `JdVa0oOqQAr0ZMdtcTwHrQ==`

**Questions**:

1. What is happening? When do jboss use `base64` algorithm and when `md5`
2. What is the difference between `hashAlgorithm` and `hashEncoding`?

Comment: Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for ~100ms, save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.
See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.
See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is happening? When do jboss use base64 algorithm and when md5

MD5 is the hash algorithm and Base64 is the output character encoding.

A [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is what defines which characters correspond to a byte or series of bytes.

[MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is a cryptographic hash algorithm that produces a 16-byte output of 8-bit bytes, not characters. Not all 8-bit bytes are printable characters.

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) accepts an array of bytes and produces a printable character string. It is generally used the an array of bytes needs to be encoded to a printable character string.

2. What is the difference between hashAlgorithm and hashEncoding?

Some hash functions allow specification of the hash algorithm `hashAlgorithm` such as MD5, SHA1, SHA-256, etc that is used to hash the output encoding `hashEncoding` such as hexadecimal or Base64. This allows one function call to both hash the input with a selected hash algorithm and selected output encoding in one call.